# HTML iframe maximum height, height:100% not working

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to set the height of iframe to expand to the rest of available space (ie windowsHeight - menuHeight - footerHeight), as used in contentFrame, which does not work for me. It works when height is set to specific pixels.The width:100% works. Because the app is a legacy app,  it should be compatible with IE 10/11, Chrome, and Firefox.

index.htm

```
<body>
<iframe name="menuFrame" src="menu.htm" frameborder="1" style="height:40px; width: 100%;">
</iframe>
<iframe name="contentFrame" src="content.htm" frameborder="1" style="height:100%; width: 100%;">
</iframe>
<iframe name="footerFrame" src="footer.htm" frameborder="1" style="height:15px; width: 100%;">
</iframe>
</body>
```

menu.htm

```
<body>
menu
</body>
```

content.htm

```
<body style="border: solid 1 black;height: 100%;">
content
</body>
```

footer.htm

```
<body>
footer
</body>
```

**Update**
Thanks all for your help. I tested LGSon's only, which is easier for me to understand.

Comment: Height is 100% of what, do you think?

Comment: The height of iframe to expand to the rest of available space (ie windowsHeight - menuHeight - footerHeight)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to make this work.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;             /* need for iframe height 100% to work */
}
iframe {
  box-sizing: border-box;   /* make the border size be included in the height */
  display: block;           /* make them block to fix white space margin */
  width: 100%;
}
iframe:nth-child(1) {
  height: 40px;
}
iframe:nth-child(3) {
  height: 15px;
}
iframe:nth-child(2) {
  height: calc(100% - 55px);  /* 55px = sum of menu/footer iframe height */
}
```

```html
  <iframe name="menuFrame" src="menu.htm" frameborder="1">
  </iframe>
  <iframe name="contentFrame" src="content.htm" frameborder="1">
  </iframe>
  <iframe name="footerFrame" src="footer.htm" frameborder="1">
  </iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to go:

You have to make sure to add a `width` to your iframe. Also, it could be a good idea to set it to `display:block;` value to your iframe.

Example for 100% height and 100% width iframe inline:

```
<iframe src="PLACE_YOUR_URL_THERE.html" height="100%" width="100%" style="display: block;" />
```

Of course, the best way is always to set it by CSS if it is possible. But both works.

N.B: In your CSS, add this property:

```
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}
```

So you will make sure that your body and html tag takes 100% of the current viewport height

Answer (score 0):

If you are free to use `calc` (http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) and viewport units (http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), you can get the middle iframe to fill the remaining space by doing the following:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
div,
iframe {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
 height: 100vh;
}

iframe {
 display: block;
 width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<iframe name="menuFrame" frameborder="1" src="" style="height:40px;">
</iframe>
<iframe name="contentFrame" frameborder="1" src="" style="height:calc(100vh - 55px);">
</iframe>
<iframe name="footerFrame" frameborder="1" src="" style="height:15px;">
</iframe>
```